# Instructions in Chrome Extension using OAuth2 tutorial out of date. How do I find the key?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I've been out of the developer game for about 20 years and its showing.  I'm attempting to build a chrome extension that uses OAuth2 so it can access events on a user's Google calendar.

I'm following the instructions here:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tut_oauth

Where I'm getting jammed up is in the section labeled, "Upload to the Developer Dashboard".  It uses this section to generate a key that must be in the manifest, but I think these instructions were written using an older version of the Chrome Developer Dashboard.  When I upload, the "more info" option that displays the key doesn't seem to be there.

I stopped dead in my tracks because the only way for me to make forward progress is for me to get events from google calendar.  Any thoughts for a recently rebranded "newbie".  If the route in this tutorial is no longer valid, that's fine, I just need some way of accessing my calendar programmatically while I am developing the extension.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to navigate to the legacy developer dashboard interface in the extension's "More Info" link to get the public key.

First you need to opt out of the new dashboard which you can do by clicking `Show More` on the bottom right of the dashboard view.

You can then view both the new and legacy dashboards based on the URL.

Legacy dashboard: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard

Once you have the key you need to add it to your `manifest.json` file

```
"key": "MIIBIxxxxxx"
```